# ¿Cómo agrupar dataframe en un plot con varios grupos con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Me gustaría hacer un gráfico del siguiente DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['España', 'Madrid', 3, 2, 50, 70, 30], 
   ['España', 'Alicante', 0, 2, 28, 40, 20],
   ['España', 'Barcelona', 2, 2, 40, 70, 30], 
   ['España', 'Granada', 4, 1, 28, 30, 15],
   ['Francia', 'Paris', 0, 3, 60, 60, 30],
   ['Francia', 'Burdeos', 6, 2, 35, 50, 35],
   ['Francia', 'Lyon', 4, 2, 45, 50, 25],
   ['Francia', 'Toulouse', 1, 2, 55, 55, 40],
   ['Alemania', 'Munich', 2, 2, 65, 65, 20],
   ['Alemania', 'Berlin', 1, 2, 70, 65, 30],
   ['Alemania', 'Frankfurt', 1, 2, 60, 45, 35],
   ['Alemania', 'Bremen', 0, 2, 55, 60, 25],
   ['ReinoUnido', 'Londres', 2, 2, 80, 70, 15],
   ['ReinoUnido', 'Leeds', 2, 2, 65, 45, 20],
   ['ReinoUnido', 'Manchester', 2, 2, 70, 65, 20],
   ['ReinoUnido', 'Bristol', 1, 2, 50, 45, 35]],
   columns=['Pais', 'Ciudad', 'Hijos', 'Coches', 'Salario', 'Gasto','Ocio'])
```

Como se puede comprobar se tiene una columna (País) que tiene varias opciones. Lo que no he conseguido es sacar un gráfico (tipo bar) con diferentes colores que tenga agrupado el país y dentro del país estén las ciudades.

O cuál seria la mejor opción para representar esos datos?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No está claro cuál es la mejor opción para representar tus datos, pues la mejor opción depende de qué datos quieras comparar entre sí.

De cualquier forma te recomiendo usar `seaborn` que admite muchas formas muy flexibles de representar gráficamente datos con muchas dimensiones, como parece ser tu caso.

Para que los datos sean más fácilmente representables con seaborn, interesa que el dataframe esté en un formato normalmente denominado "tidy", en el que todos los valores numéricos sean una sola columna, y tengas otra columna adicional que indica qué es lo que representa ese valor numérico.

Es decir, interesaría que en lugar de estar así:

```html
          Pais      Ciudad  Hijos  Coches  Salario  Gasto  Ocio
0       España      Madrid      3       2       50     70    30
1       España    Alicante      0       2       28     40    20
2       España   Barcelona      2       2       40     70    30
3       España     Granada      4       1       28     30    15
4      Francia       Paris      0       3       60     60    30
5      Francia     Burdeos      6       2       35     50    35
6      Francia        Lyon      4       2       45     50    25
7      Francia    Toulouse      1       2       55     55    40
8     Alemania      Munich      2       2       65     65    20
9     Alemania      Berlin      1       2       70     65    30
10    Alemania   Frankfurt      1       2       60     45    35
11    Alemania      Bremen      0       2       55     60    25
12  ReinoUnido     Londres      2       2       80     70    15
13  ReinoUnido       Leeds      2       2       65     45    20
14  ReinoUnido  Manchester      2       2       70     65    20
15  ReinoUnido     Bristol      1       2       50     45    35
```

tu dataframe esté así:

```
          Pais   Ciudad variable  valor
0       España   Madrid    Hijos      3
1       España   Madrid   Coches      2
2       España   Madrid  Salario     50
3       España   Madrid    Gasto     70
4       España   Madrid     Ocio     30
..         ...      ...      ...    ...
75  ReinoUnido  Bristol    Hijos      1
76  ReinoUnido  Bristol   Coches      2
77  ReinoUnido  Bristol  Salario     50
78  ReinoUnido  Bristol    Gasto     45
79  ReinoUnido  Bristol     Ocio     35
```

### Cómo convertir los datos a formato "tidy"

Una forma sencilla es fijar como index las columnas que interesa "fijas" (ciudad y pais) y después aplicar un `stack()`, que crea una nueva columna cuyos valores son las cadenas que antes estaban en los nombres de columna.

Es decir:

```
df.set_index(["Pais", "Ciudad"]).stack()
```

te lo dejará así:

```html
Pais        Ciudad          
España      Madrid   Hijos       3
                     Coches      2
                     Salario    50
                     Gasto      70
                     Ocio       30
                                ..
ReinoUnido  Bristol  Hijos       1
                     Coches      2
                     Salario    50
                     Gasto      45
                     Ocio       35
```

muy cerca ya de la forma que necesitamos. Basta un `reset_index()` y algunos detalles para tener las columnas nuevas con nombres apropiados.

En definitiva:

```
data = (df.set_index(["Pais", "Ciudad"])
          .stack()
          .reset_index(name="valor")
          .rename(columns={"level_2": "variable"})
```

te dejará un dataframe exactamente en el formato antes buscado, ideal para plotear con seaborn.

### Plot con seaborn

A través de su función `catplot()` seaborn te permite agrupar los gráficos de muchas formas, según los parámetros que le pases. De forma general puede crear de golpe una grilla de gráficas, en la que cada fila de la grilla signifique algo, cada columna signifique otra cosa, y dentro de cada elemento de la grilla tienes una gráfica en la que el eje X es otra variable, el eje Y otra más, e incluso puedes distinguir variables adicionales por colores.

Asi por ejemplo:

- `col="Pais"` hará que las "columnas" de la grilla correspondan al pais. Es decir, hará una gráfica separada para cada pais, y las pondrá una al lado de otra, de derecha a izquierda en la misma fila (en este ejemplo no uso `row=` por lo que la grilla tendrá una única fila de gráficas)
- `x="Ciudad"` hace que dentro de cada gráfica el eje x represente diferentes ciudades
- `hue="variable"` que cada barra del gráfico de barras tenga un color diferente y represente una categoría diferente de las que hay en la columna "variable" (en tu caso, habría una barra para "Hijos", otra para "Coches", etc.) Además creará una leyenda para explicar qué significa cada color
- `y="valor"` hará que la altura de cada barra se tome de la columna "valor"
- `sharex=False` hará que cada gráfica tenga su eje X independiente del de las otras gráficas (lo que tiene mucho sentido en este caso ya que cada Pais tiene diferentes ciudades).

En resumen, con una línea como esta:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(col="Pais", x="Ciudad", hue="variable",
    y="valor", sharex=False, legend_out=True,
    kind="bar",  data=data)
```

Te crea la siguiente fila de gráficas:

[image: Resultado]

### ¿Es esta la mejor gráfica?

Yo diría que no... estás comparando en cada plot variables que quizás no sean comparables entre sí. ¿Qué sentido tiene comparar el número de hijos con el número de coches o con el salario? (especialmente porque incluso estarán en otras unidades, ya que el número de hijos será típicamente de una cifra pero el salario puede tener tres cifras o más, dependiendo de la moneda en que se mida).

Parece más lógico poder comparar una sola de esas variables (ej: número de hijos) entre diferentes ciudades, e incluso entre diferentes países (sin tener en cuenta la ciudad, sino solo obteniendo las diferentes muestras para cada pais).

Por ejemplo:

```
sns.catplot(x="Pais", y="valor", kind="box",
     data=data[data.variable=="Hijos"])
```

Produce:

[image: Grafica]

En este caso he optado por una gráfica tipo "box" que muestra la distribución estadística de una variable. Al haber usado `x="Pais"`, seaborn en cada tick del eje X representará un país, y para cada pais encontrará varios valores de la variable "Hijos" (un valor en cada ciudad). Lo que hará será pintar una "caja" vertical que representa la variabilidad de esos valores. Por ejemplo, en España varía entre 0 y 4 (marcado por "los bigotes" fuera de las cajas), pero los valores más frecuentes están entre 1.5 y 3.2 (los límites de la caja), y el percentil 50% (o mediana) en 2.5 (la línea horizontal dentro de la caja). En Francia, aunque la mediana es la misma, vemos que hay más disparidad en los datos (la caja es mayor).

O si en lugar de centrarte en una variable sola ("Hijos") quieres verlas todas, podrías usar `col="variable"` para obtener una gráfica separada para cada variable, junto con `sharey=False` para que cada una tenga su propio eje Y (lo que tiene sentido porque no son unidades comparables). Así:

```py
sns.catplot(col="variable", x="Pais", y="valor", 
            kind="box", sharey=False, data=data)
```

Y obtienes

[image: Otra gráfica más]

Y si en el código anterior cambias `"box"` por `"bar"`, te sale esta otra gráfica (gráfica de velas):

[image: Y otra más]

en la que la altura de cada barra ("vela") es el promedio de esa variable (ej: promedio de hijos en España, medido entre las diferentes ciudades), pero tiene una "mecha" que indica la variabilidad de la medida.

Comment: Primero muchas gracias. Quería unir todo en una misma gráfica porque he creado este ejemplo simple para resolver el caso, pero mi caso real no es ese. Y es la mejor manera de visualizarlo con todos los datos juntos en un mismo plot. Intentaba hacerlo con matplotlib bar plot sé que se puede pero no me salía. En cuanto a Seaborn parece super interesante y le ehcaré un ojo sobre todo como te ha quedado a ti es lo que buscaba pero con matplotlib. Muchas gracias por la respuesta me ha sido muy útil.